# Using facebook fql, how do I find where a school is?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

[Note: the first two answers, which includes the one I wrote, do not yet deal with the "optional" fql.multiquery issue.]

When I am using facebook's fql, I can get a list of schools I have attended, or that friends have attended.  Specifically, I can get the school's name, and it's facebook id.  However, I do not know how to query for deeper information about these schools.

Specifically, I would like to find out where the schools were located.  But, I do not know what facebook graph entity (or whatever else) those school ids are part of.

How would I find out from facebook where these schools are located?

Optional:  It would be even better if this can be done in the same multiquery that returned the lists of schools in the first place (this would be a query against the user table for my id and another query against the user table for some ids of my friends).

Here's an expanded version of the optional part mentioned in the above paragraph (note that I tried adding this as a separate question, but when I went in make the illustrative data more relevant, I saw that it had silently vanished.  So I am assuming I tripped over some feature of stack overflow designed to weed out questions which are too similar to each other.  So, instead, let's just say that this is a clarification of what I meant, in the above paragraph)

Using facebook's javascript sdk, this fails, silently:

```
FB.login(function(response){
    disp('loginResponse', response);
    var userQuery= FB.Data.query(
  'select uid,name,education from user where uid= {0}'
      , response.session.uid);

    var friendlist = FB.Data.query(
     'select uid2 from friend where uid1 = {0} order by rand() limit 10'
     , response.session.uid);

    var friends = FB.Data.query(
  'select uid,name,education from user where uid in (select uid2 from {0})'
     , friendlist);

    var friendSchools= FB.Data.query(
  'select page_id,name,location from page where page_id in (select education.school.id from {0})'
  , friends);

    self.queries= [userQuery, friendlist, friends, friendSchools];
    FB.Data.waitOn(queries
      , function() {alert(1)});
    })
```

If I remove the friendSchools element from the queries array, it works just fine, and a friend might be represented by an object like this:

```
{
  uid: '...',
  name: '...',
  education:
    [
      {
        school:
          {
            id: '115920001751600',
            name: 'Burlington High School'
          },
        year:
          {
            id: '138792749476094',
            name: '1978'
          },
        type: 'High School'
      },
      {
        school:
          {
            id: '20697868961',
            name: 'Boston University'
          },
        degree:
          {
            id: '188387604516411',
            name: 'BS'
          },
        year:
          {
            id: '103823546338323',
            name: '1982'
          },
        type: 'College'
      }
    ]
}
```

So, how do I restructure the where clause in the friendSchools query so that that query can be performed?

In other words, how can I use fql.multiquery to find information about schools (or other such entities) returned elsewhere in the multiquery?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using batch requests (more information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to query the graph based on the schools ID you already have. The location of the school can be retrieved in it's default basic information returned (example below).

```
{
   "id": "6192688417",
   "name": "Stanford University",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/41571_6192688417_2310209_s.jpg",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/stanford",
   "likes": 203153,
   "category": "Education",
   "website": "http://www.stanford.edu",
   "username": "stanford",
   "founded": "1891",
   "location": {
      "street": "450 Serra Mall",
      "city": "Stanford",
      "state": "CA",
      "country": "United States",
      "zip": "94305",
      "latitude": 37.42895,
      "longitude": -122.1697
   },
   "public_transit": "http://transportation.stanford.edu",
   "general_info": "Located between San Francisco and San Jose in the heart of Silicon Valley, Stanford University is recognized as one of the world's leading research and teaching institutions.\n\nLeland and Jane Stanford founded the University to \"promote the public welfare by exercising an influence on behalf of humanity and civilization.\" Stanford opened its doors in 1891, and more than a century later, it remains dedicated to finding solutions to the great challenges of the day and to preparing our students for leadership in today's complex world.",
   "checkins": 9938
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this information isn't verified or inputted by Facebook itself, so what you retrieve might not always be accurate or complete.

Comment: Ok, I see -- the id itself is a node by itself on the graph, with no further qualification required.  That said, the batch api looks ugly for my purposes (you use jsonp in a <script tag, but batch wants a form), so I'll have to search for an alternative, (though experimenting to see if I can get batch to work using a GET might be adequate, if kludgy.)

Answer (score 0):

And, it looks like to get fql to work I want to be querying the page table.  For example:

```
select name,location from page where page_id = 87873693141
```

(That said, I'm still trying to figure out how to extract the list my education's school ids into the where clause for a multi-query.)